# output rows to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a script that successfully prints a header and rows in the terminal output, but when I try to do the same thing for a CSV output it fails and says it expects an array.

I want to try to get  lined up for just a simple csv that would ideally open in excel with different columns

```
print("Frame,Group,Average Days,Total Units Sold,Total Placements\n");
//$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach($groupedByFrame as $frame){
print($frame['frame'].','.$frame['group'].','.round($frame['avg'],3).','.$frame['qty'].','.$frame['placements']."\n");
  //fputcsv($file,explode(',',$frame));
}

//fclose($file);
```

Comment: So you got that "it expects an array" error when you used fputcsv statement? fputcsv has the second argument as array http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: But is there a way to do it based off this loop without an array?

Comment: What is the problem with the `$frame` array?

Comment: Well the frame array is the main array being output, but would I have to change the csv format to use it? If I comment out the print statements and uncomment the csv lines, then it says it expects an array and doesn't get one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the format (and order) of the `$frame` array, you could create another one:

```
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

// header
$header = ['Frame','Group','Average Days','Total Units Sold','Total Placements'];
fputcsv($file, $header);

// data
foreach($groupedByFrame as $frame)
{
    $array = [
        $frame['frame'],
        $frame['group'],
        round($frame['avg'],3),
        $frame['qty'],
        $frame['placements']
    ];
    fputcsv($file, $array);
}
fclose($file);
```

If you want to output the `$frame` directly, you could use:

```
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
$header = ['Frame','Group','Average Days','Total Units Sold','Total Placements'];
fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach($groupedByFrame as $frame)
{
    fputcsv($file, $frame);
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explode the inner array, it's already an array.

Try this:

```
//print("Frame,Group,Average Days,Total Units Sold,Total Placements\n");
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach($groupedByFrame as $frame) 
{ 

 //print($frame['frame'].','.$frame['group'].','.round($frame['avg'],3).','.$frame['qty'].','.$frame['placements']."\n");
  fputcsv($file,$frame);
}

fclose($file);
```